# Need to print the send messages to 10 partitions randomly using kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Hi I am using Kafka API 0.10.0.1 . I have created the topic kartik and has 10 partitions. From this producer code I am getting output as all the 10 messages are going 10 partitions. But the problem is each partition is getting 10 messages. What I want is each partitions should get only one message i.e. the partitions should get 1  message randomly . Or if we have 50 messages then these messages should be allocated to these partitions randomly, not that each partition gets 50 messages.

public class Producerpar {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

      String topic = "kartik";
      if(topic == null){
         System.out.println("there has to be some topic");
        return;
      }

 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
 props.put("acks", "all");
 props.put("retries", 0);
 props.put("batch.size", 16384);
 props.put("linger.ms", 1);
 props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
 props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
 props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");



 Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props); 

String msg = "Hey there .. How are you doing ?";    
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    List<PartitionInfo> infoList = producer.partitionsFor(topic);
    for(PartitionInfo partitioninfo : infoList){ 
    System.out.println(partitioninfo.partition());


    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));


 System.out.println("Message:  " + msg +  " are sent to partitions: " +partitioninfo.partition()  );


 }
```

}

Comment: Did you forget a ending curly bracket for the inner for loop in which case the producer sends 100 messages in all?

Comment: @Kartikeya Gupta: its because you are iterating each and every message(which is 1 to 10) for all the partitions, remove this for each `for(PartitionInfo partitioninfo : infoList){ `

Comment: @Shankar : If I delete that it will print the message in the console not the partition id to which the messages are going . what i want is it should also show in console that to which partition id it is going.

Comment: @KartikeyaGupta: Did you try my answer with callback?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `callback` when you send the message, that will return you the `RecordMetaData`, from which you can get the partition id of the message.

**For example:**

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i))
            producer.send(record,
                           new Callback() {
                               public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                                   int partitionId = metadata.partition();
                               }
                           });

     }
```